# Recognizing Subgroups of Groups of Functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I don't know Calculus, so I'll just shoot from intuition where Calculus is required :)

$\mathcal F(\mathbb R)$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb R $ to $\mathbb R $.

$\mathcal C(\mathbb R)$ is the set of all continuous functions from $\mathbb R $ to $\mathbb R $.

$\mathcal D(\mathbb R)$ is the set of all differentiable functions from $\mathbb R $ to $\mathbb R $.

> $G= <\mathcal F(\mathbb R), +), H={f \in \mathcal F(\mathbb R): f(x) = 0, \forall x \in [0, 1]}.$

Let $f, g \in H $. Then $[f + g](x) = f(x) + g(x) = 0 + 0 = 0, \forall x \in [0, 1]$ Also, $[-f](x) = -f(x) = -0 = 0, \forall x \in [0, 1]$ So, $H$ is a subgroup of $G.$

> $G = <\mathcal F(\mathbb R), +>, H = \{f \in \mathcal F(\mathbb R): f(-x) = -f(x)\}$

Let $f, g \in H $. Then $[f + g](-x) = f(-x) + g(-x) = -f(x) + (-g(x)) = -(f(x) + g(x)).$

Since $f \in H, f(-x) = -f(x)\}.$ So, $[-f](-x) = -f(-x) = -(-f(x)) = f(x).$ So, $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

> $G = <\mathcal F(\mathbb R), +>, H = \{f \text { is periodic of period $\pi$}\}.$

Let $f, g \in H $. Then $[f + g](x) = f(x) + g(x) = f(x + n \pi) + g(x + n \pi) = [f + g](x + n \pi).$

Since $f \in H, f(x) = f(x + n \pi)$. Then, $[-f](x) = -f(x + n \pi).$ So, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

> $G = <\mathcal C(\mathbb R), +>, H = \{f \in \mathcal C(\mathbb R): \int_0^1 f(x) dx = 0\}.$

Let $f, g \in H $. Then $[f + g](x) = f(x) + g(x). So, \int_0^1 f(x) dx + \int_0^1 f(x) dx = 0 + 0 = 0.$

Since $f \in H, \int_0^1 f(x) dx = 0$. So, $\int_0^1 [-f](x) dx = \int_0^1 -f(x) dx = -\int_0^1 f(x) dx =-1 \cdot 0 = 0.$ So, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

> $G = <\mathcal D(\mathbb R), +>, H = \{f \in \mathcal D(\mathbb R): \frac {df}{dx} \text { is a constant}\}.$

Since $f \in H, \frac {df}{dx} \text { is a constant}$. The sum of two constants is constant. A negative constant is still a constant. So, $H$ is  a subgroup of $G$.

> $G = <\mathcal F(\mathbb R), +), H = \{f \in \mathcal F(\mathbb R): f(x) \in \mathbb Z, \forall x \in \mathbb R\}$

Let $f, g \in H $. Then $[f + g](x) = f(x) + g(x)$. $\mathbb Z$ is closed under addition, so $[f + g](x) \in \mathbb Z$. Also, $[-f](x) = -f(x) \in \mathbb Z.$ So, $H$ is  a subgroup of $G$.

Please, check my work.

Comment: How are you attempting to do group theory without knowing calculus? That doesn't seem to be the standard, rather obvious order of complexity in learning mathematics.